# views slideshow jQuery Cycle Custom Options how to use?

Tags: 7, javascript, views

I display a view using slideshow format. To slide images I use controls only. After installing json2.js library I can add additional options displayed here http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/options.html I think, using options it might be possible to add active classes on controls for better styling. I need to add first and last class. Has anyone experience how to use it? Thank you. Adding first/last classes typical way (checking this option in views does not work and in this situation it would not solve it)

Comment: add first and last class to controls or slide??

Comment: @monymirza Yes exactly, that is what I try to achieve. The question is HOW. How to add active class to active slide, how to add first class to previous controll button on first lide, how to add last class on next controll button on last slide.